# i am getting AVOID eager loading detected even though i have not included it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

i am using bullet gem to detect N + 1 queries

```
offers.
    includes(
      :timezone,
      { completed_transition: [:talents_job] }
    )
```

but i am getting

```
user: prateek
GET api_url
AVOID eager loading detected
  CompletedTransition => [:pipeline_step]
  Remove from your finder: :includes => [:pipeline_step]
Call stack
```

what can be the possible issue?

Comment: do you query on `completed_transition` ?  something like: `offers.map {|offer| offer.completed_transition.where()... }`.

Comment: do you have default_scope on model Timezone calling `includes`?

Comment: no i do not have the default scope for that

Comment: Can you share the setup of the code for the models involved? Offer, CompletedTransition, TalentsJob?